# Delete from database in Symfony 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use a delete function for Symfony 2, which gives me an error

Routing.yml

```
home_homepage_deleteuser:
   path:   /homepage/delete_users/{id}
   defaults: {_controller: HomeHomepageBundle:Default:deleteuser}
   methods: [GET, POST]
```

Defaultcontroller.php

```
 public function deleteuseraction(Users $users)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $users = $em -> getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Users')->find($idusers);
        $em-> remove($users);
        $em -> flush();

        return $this->redirectToroute('home_homepage_userlist');
    }
```

Userlist.html.twig

```
<a href="{{ path('home_homepage_deleteuser') }}" 
class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</a>
```

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY6i0.png)

Comment: You're not deleting "a database", you want to delete from a database... it's fairly different. What kind of error did it give to you?

Comment: No route found for "GET /homepage/delete_users/" (from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/homepage/userlist")

Comment: You need to pass Id parameter to this url this way `<a href="{{ path('home_homepage_deleteuser', { 'id': user.getId() }) }}" 
class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</a> `, where user is an instance of Users, that you may pass to twig (or access it in the way you want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see at least 5 issues here.

- it should be `DefaultController.php` instead of `Defaultcontroller.php`
- it should be `deleteuserAction` instead of `deleteuseraction`
- `(Users $users)` argument is incorrect unless you use param converting (you don't provide info about if you do). If so, then you're overriding this variable later which doesn't make sense.
- `$idusers` is undefined
- You do not pass user ID to `{{ path('home_homepage_deleteuser') }}`

So there is a lot of work to do here. Also you don't even tell us what is the error, so there may be several other issues.

Comment: (Users $users) is magic in symfony routing and probably some other things as well. It sees the id in the route and does a select on the Users and tries to find that id. and boom, you don't need to get the entitymanager and do a select which saves you 1-3 lines.

Comment: I know about that. It's called ParamConverter, but it's not used here. You have to configure it to work.

Comment: Not used in the function, yeah.

Comment: Actually it is. The [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) say: _If you use type hinting as in the example above, you can even omit the @ParamConverter annotation altogether:_

Comment: @EmanuelOster it seems you're right. I've updated my answer a little bit.

Comment: Any link to refer?

Answer (score 0):

I found it , the code should be look like this.. No i'm the idiot.

DefaultController.php

```
public function deleteuseraction($id)

    {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $users = $em -> getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Users')->find($id);
    $em -> remove($users);
    $em -> flush();

    return $this->redirectToroute('home_homepage_userlist');
    }
```

Userlist.html.twig

```
<a href="{{ path('home_homepage_deleteuser', { 'id': deposit.idusers }) }}" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Delete</a>
```

routing.yml

```
home_homepage_deleteuser:
   path:   /homepage/delete_users/{id}
   defaults: {_controller: HomeHomepageBundle:Default:deleteuser}
   methods: [GET, POST]
```